# from Batchfile called Programm doesn't write file to Folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a Batch file which executes a Program for each tiff-File in a Folder. The Programm analyses the Picture and writes the result to a File in the Folder. If I execute this by hand every thing works fine. If I run the Batchfile then there are no File written.

The Program, the pictures and the Batchfile are all in the same Folder.

the Programm is called like this: `for  %%i in (.\*.tif) do cpix_laengs.exe %%i`

In Case it may matters the fileoutput is realised by this command:
 
  `outputfile = ("./out-laengs__" + argv1 + ".txt");
  ofstream efile(outputfile, std::ofstream::out)`

I'd like to know why there are no files written and how to avoid this issu. So i don't have to execute the programm for all the files by hand.

Comment: Are there blanks in the image file names? If so, you need double quotes, as in `for  %%i in (.\*.tif) do cpix_laengs.exe "%%i"`.

Comment: No there are no spaces in the filenames. But the complete Path contains a Space and a special german character.

Comment: I suggest you temporarily add an `echo` command to the script, so that you can see what commands are being attempted, as in `for  %%i in (.\*.tif) do echo cpix_laengs.exe %%i`. It may reveal what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i'd tryed this already in a slightly diffrent way but forgott to mention it. It doesen't work. It prints out   `cpix_laengs.exe .\43-3.TIF` or `"cpix_laengs.exe .\43-3.TIF"` depending on the format but it doesent print the other output I expect from the program.  But as already mentioned if I enter it directly into the shell it works with or without quotations.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, unless the current drive or directory changes. You can check this by adding `%CD%` to the `echo` command, as in `for %%i in (.\*.tif) do echo In directory %CD%: cpix_laengs.exe "%%i"`.

Comment: OMG, my bad. I just wrote echo just before the command, so it only printed it and never actually exceuted it. And I fixed the 1st problem by removing `".\"` from `in (.\*.tif)`.